# getObjectInfo/getPicklistValues permissions needed in public community

Tags: permissions, profile, metadata, force.com-sites, lwc-wire-adapter

What are the permissions needed to use getObjectInfo (needed for default record type) && getPicklistValues wire adapters in public community?

I've added but I'm getting 401 when accessing `webruntime/api/services/data/v58.0/ui-api/object-info/Contact?language=en-US&asGuest=true&htmlEncode=false`

```
errorCode : "UNAUTHORIZED"
message: "Unauthorized access"
```

I've granted Contact Read and field read permissions for the public profile, but that doesn't seem to be enough.

I'm using a custom LWR template if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you try to give Contact Read and field read permissions for community profiles!

Answer (score 0):

I just sorted this out on an LWR, you have to check the "Allow guest users to access public APIs" setting in the Workspace under "Preferences" and also give access to the necessary fields on the Object.